# How to check if a key exists in nested JSON parsed object in c#

Tags: c#, json

I have JSON which is similar to below format :

```
{
    "id": "S01",
    "submittedBy": "A12345",
    "orderData": {
        "items": [
            {
                "key": "Item1",
                "value": "10"
            },
            {
                "key": "Item2",
                "value": "20"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

By some means I'm getting this JSON string into `jsonString` variable in my application.

Now I have few classes similar to below :

```
[DataContract]
public class Order
{
    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "submittedBy")]
        public string SubmittedBy { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "orderData")]
        public OrderData OrderData { get; set; }    

}

[DataContract]
public class OrderData
{
    [DataMember(Name = "items")]
        public List<Items> Items { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Items 
{
    [DataMember(Name="key")]
        public string Key { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="value")]
        public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

After getting the JSON string, I'm doing this.

```
Order order = new Order();
order = JObject.Parse(jsonString).ToObject<Order>();
```

Now in `order` object, if I have to check if there is any key:"Item3" without running a loop through it, how do I check it?

Any help is much appreciated.

PS: Apologies for the question title. Any suggestions/editing for anything more appropriate is welcome.

Comment: Given the shape of the provided JSON, you have no choice but to loop through the `items`. Do you have the option to change the JSON shape?

Comment: @dana No I do not have option to change it as rest of the code is already written based on it.

Comment: `JObject.Parse(jsonString).ToObject<Order>()` is a waste of processing time, that should be just `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Order>(jsonString)`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Thanks for correcting me. But you don't have to down vote though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use LINQ `.Any()`:

```
order.OrderData.Items.Any(q => q.Key == "item3")
```

You also may want to add some null-reference checks:

```
order.OrderData?.Items?.Any(q => q.Key == "item3") ?? false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ's [`Any()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.any?view=netframework-4.7.2) like this:

```
bool exists = order.OrderData != null && 
    order.OrderData.Items != null &&
    order.OrderData.Items.Any(x => x.Key == "Item3")
```

See also this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/determine-if-any-or-all-elements-in-a-sequence-satisfy-a-condition).

Side note: The `new Order()` in your code is superfluous. You can simplify it to this:

```
Order order = JObject.Parse(jsonString).ToObject<Order>();
```

Comment: Why would the OP want to parse to a JObect? What a waste, that should be `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Order>(jsonString)`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto That's really not something we should be dealing with. The OP's problem is something else.